# See All Files Changed in Multiple Changesets in VSTS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2005

Does anyone know how get a listing of all files changed in multiple changesets in Visual Studio Team System 2005?  I basically want to see a listing of all files changed from the start of a development effort till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the power tools installed:

```
# get-tfschangeset doesn't support arrays, so you have to loop
100, 200, 300 | % { get-tfschangeset $_ } | select-tfsitem | select -unique path | sort

# powershell also has a range operator...
100..105 | % { get-tfschangeset $_ } | select-tfsitem
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use TF.exe from the command line to get at an awful lot of information very easily.

Even if it's not possible to directly extract the info you want in one call, it would be easy to write a small program that calls TF.exe to get a list of the changesets you're interested in, and then calls it again for each changeset to retrieve the file lists.

Start a Visual Studio Command Prompt (from your start menu) and enter `tf.exe /?` to get to the documentation.